# A "constexpr" expression that takes too long

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constexpr

The following code does not compile in [visual C++](https://godbolt.org/z/owOnko), because the "*expression did not evaluate to a constant*".

```
constexpr auto func() {
    for (unsigned long long i = 1; i < 10000000UL; ++i);
    return 123;
}
constexpr auto f = func();
```

In general, expressions that take too long to compute, cannot be made `constexpr`. Is it possible to give the compiler more time to evaluate such 'difficult' `constexpr`essions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `/constexpr:steps` is exactly the option that describes how long the compiler can think about `constexpr`essions.